# Android 4.0 unpacks the wrong eabi for included library

Tags: android-ndk

Here is the situation: I've built a native library for re-distribution in other apps. Because we're using ARMv7 NEON, we ship two versions of the library: One for most devices and a "fallback" limited capability version for ARMv5/ARMv6. So far so good and this has worked well.

However, for some reason a newly created app running on a Nexus S with Android 4.0.3 is picking up the wrong (armeabi rather than armeabi-v7a) version of the library.

If we dig into the device filesystem, we find that /data/app/my_app.apk contains the correct versions of the library. However, when Android extracts it to /data/data/my_app, we find that /data/data/my_app/lib/my_lib.so is the armeabi version. But, strangely, /data/data/my_other_app/lib/my_lib.so is the correct armeabi-v7a version.

So the questions are:
1) WTF??
2) How does Android decide which eabi to extract from the APK?

Comment: I should also mention that my_app.apk runs perfectly well on an Android 2.2.1 phone. Which leads us back to question #1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is known bug in ICS - it chooses wrong library.

Read about it here:

- http://www.moodstocks.com/2012/03/20/ice-cream-sandwich-why-native-code-support-sucks/
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/N8FLjvM81pg/2rYeClQZcckJ

Comment: This seems to match what's happening, but the question remains: Why does the problem occur in one app and not the other when both are using the same bundled library?

Comment: In first link there is talk about that which library gets unpacked on armeabi-v7a depends on order of .so files in apk archive. Maybe that is what is happening.

Comment: That makes sense, but seems odd that the order is consistent (and consistently different) within each project... I've built several versions of the working app with no problem. BUT, having a separate capability library seems to work, so I'm not going to pursue it much further. Thanks for the links!!

Comment: The Moodstocks blog post says it does *not* only depend on the order of files in the archive. If you want to understand why look at the awesome comment by Jay Freeman below it.